# How to edit TFS work item email template

Tags: email, tfs

I'm new to TFS 2013 and I'm trying to edit the email template that pops up when you click the email symbol within a work type item in TFS, but I have not been able to thus far.

Specifically I want to include a custom field that has been added to the form. The research I have done points me in the the direction of the following path way: Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms\1033.

However the files here (and please forgive my ignorance if I have got this wrong) appear to control event changes across the TFS, which I don’t want to change.

My scenario is that a user wants to email a work type to another user and include a custom field in the email template. Thanks (I would have included a screen shot but stackoverflow would not let me).

Comment: To add an image hit `Ctrl+G` then drag and drop your image.

Comment: You're looking in the right place, but as you said this will control the format of all work item emails. You'll have to build conditional logic into the xsl file if you only want certain fields to show in certain scenarios.